# Regex is not checking some part of text

Tags: regex, linux, syntax, grep

I've example file with data to analyze by egrep command:

```
[IG#]
IG#
[RM#]
RM#
[IG#1234]
[IG# 1234]
[IG #1234] [RM# ]
[IG# 1234] [RM #1224]
[RM#1234]
[RM# 1234]
[RM #1234]
[RM# 1234] [IG#]
[RM# ] [IG#1234]
#1234
1234
```

My regexp looks that:

```
(RM#.*[0-9]|IG#.*[0-9]|\b([A-Z][A-Z0-9]+-[0-9]+)\b)
```

I wan't to find only rows where [RM# {digits}] AND [IG# {digits}] but it returns like using OR and results looks following:

```
[IG#1234]
[IG# 1234]
[IG# 1234] [RM #1224]
[RM#1234]
[RM# 1234]
[RM# 1234] [IG#]
[RM# ] [IG#1234]
```

Expected output is

```
[IG# 1234]
[RM# 1234]
[IG# 1234] [RM1224]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @anubhava: My expected output is where both sections [RM#] and [IG#] contains digits. Like that [IG# 1234] [RM #1224]

Comment: `|` means OR in regexp.

Comment: umm..why is expected output containing `[IG# 1234]` and `[RM# 1234]`?

Comment: the line `[IG# 1234] [RM1224]` in your expected output seems to be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to search for a line that should match two different strings in any order.. one way to do it

```
$ grep -E 'RM\s*#\s*[0-9]' ip.txt | grep -E 'IG\s*#\s*[0-9]'
[IG# 1234] [RM #1224]
```

- `\s` will match any whitespace character, use literal space if that is sufficient
- add additional constraints like checking for `[]` surrounding `RM/IG` if needed

to check it in one shot, need to create all permutations

```
$ grep -E 'RM\s*#\s*[0-9].*IG\s*#\s*[0-9]|IG\s*#\s*[0-9].*RM\s*#\s*[0-9]' ip.txt
[IG# 1234] [RM #1224]

$ # awk is better suited
$ awk '/RM\s*#\s*[0-9]/ && /IG\s*#\s*[0-9]/' ip.txt
[IG# 1234] [RM #1224]
```

Comment: Thank you Sundeep for your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

`|` is "alternative", i.e. it really means OR. There's no AND in regular expressions - either enumerate the possibilities

```
egrep 'RM ?# ?[0-9].*IG ?# ?[0-9]|IG ?# ?[0-9].*RM ?# ?[0-9]'
```

or use two greps

```
 egrep 'RM ?# ?[0-9]' file | egrep 'IG ?# ?[0-9]'
```